# Can someone tell me what this machine is?

Tags: electric-machine

It has two probes on two cables. I think it might be an xray machine but I can not be sure since there is no readable info on it. Can someone please identify it?

[image: Back of the case]

[image: Front of the case]

[image: Front of the case closeup]

Comment: It is not an x-ray machine unless it has an x-ray vacuum tube. The only piece that is half way recognizable appears to be a transformer with a low-voltage, high-current secondary. It is not large enough to be much of a welder. There appear to be a couple of parts that might be recognizable in a better photo.

Comment: Looks like [Solus Schall lasted from 1939-1963](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/Solus-Schall).

Comment: What's behind the wood panel?

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Solus-Schall](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/Solus-Schall) did indeed make X-ray equipment, but the box you have appears to be nothing more than the power supply for some larger system.

The heavy wiring suggests low voltage and high current, which is the opposite of what you'd expect for X-ray — maybe it's for some sort of heat therapy.